# split a string into a list of tuples

Tags: python

If i have a string like:

```
"user1:type1,user2:type2,user3:type3"
```

and I want to convert this to a list of tuples like so:

```
[('user1','type1'),('user2','type2'),('user3','type3')]
```

how would i go about doing this?  I'm fairly new to python but couldn't find a good example in the documentation to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: It's funny how all three answers are absolutely identical :)

Comment: @felix "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it." --zen of python

Comment: **@Jweede:** I think **obvious** is the keyword there. There are **always at least two** ways of doing something :). **Lawrence:** I see you're new to stack **overflow**. You have to accept one of the answers by clicking the checkmark found to the left of the answer, underneath the answer's "score".

Answer (score 12):

```
>>> s = "user1:type1,user2:type2,user3:type3"
>>> [tuple(x.split(':')) for x in s.split(',')]
[('user1', 'type1'), ('user2', 'type2'), ('user3', 'type3')]
```

Answer (score 5):

The cleanest way is two splits with a list comprehension:

```
str = "user1:type1,user2:type2,user3:type3"
res = [tuple(x.split(":")) for x in str.split(",")]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> s = "user1:type1,user2:type2,user3:type3"
>>> l = [tuple(user.split(":")) for user in s.split(",")]
>>> l
[('user1', 'type1'), ('user2', 'type2'), ('user3', 'type3')]
>>>
```

:)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it without for loops, you can use map and lambda:

```
map(lambda x: tuple(x.split(":")), yourString.split(","))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `split` function twice.

Try this for an example:

```
 s = "user1:type1,user2:type2,user3:type3"
 print [i.split(':') for i in s.split(',')]
```

Comment: -1 for a few reasons
1) don't use `str` as a variable name
2) this wouldn't work because the result of the first `split` is a list

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name either.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback all (and removing the downvote). I'll remember to test before I post next time. :P